# Regular Expression for validating text in VBScript

Tags: regex, vbscript

I need to validate text box value entered by user using regular expression in vbscript

Valid entry must be of the format INVXXXXX (Text should begin with INV or inv followed 5 digits)

Answer (score 0):

For that you can use the following regex:

`^(INV|inv)\d{5}$`

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/xT3uT1)